# How can I automatically add the number of the document last page to the header?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I need add the numbers of the first and last page to the header of the first page. To make it look like this:

Document title, date, **pp. 1 - 30**

The number of the first page is `\thepage`, because are in the header of itself.

I'm using `fancyhdr` to make the headers. How can I do it preferably without using the `lastpage` package?

If the document is twosided with `\cleradoublepage`, the `lastpage` package doesn't work well if I add `\AtEndDocument{Some text}` in the preamble. Here an MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{lastpage}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lastpage
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancyhead[C]{Document title, \today, \textbf{pp.\ \pageref{FirstPage}~-~\pageref{LastPage}}}
\AtBeginDocument{\label{FirstPage}}%
\AtEndDocument{Some text that I need put at the end of text. \cleardoublepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
   \section{First section}\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following does exactly what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{lastpage}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lastpage
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancyhead[C]{Document title, \today, \textbf{pp.\ \pageref{FirstPage}~-~\pageref{LastPage}}}
\AtBeginDocument{\label{FirstPage}}%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}\lipsum[1-20]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[21-40]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[41-60]
\end{document}
```

The first page label `FirstPage` is set using `\AtBeginDocument`, while the last page label is obtain via the [`lastpage` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/lastpage) as `LastPage`. A label for the first page is required if you plan on setting a different first page counter. If you don't want to use the `lastpage` package, you can use

```
\AtEndDocument{\label{LastPage}}
```

which should work in most cases. The cases where this might not work include end-of-document unprocessed floats, for example. The [`pageslts` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/pageslts) provides a work-around in such cases by provided access to a `VeryLastPage` label:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{pageslts}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pageslts
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancyhead[C]{Document title, \today, \textbf{pp.\ \pageref{FirstPage}~-~\pageref{VeryLastPage}}}
\AtBeginDocument{\label{FirstPage}}%
\AtEndDocument{Some text that I need put at the end of text. \cleardoublepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
   \section{First section}\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

The rest of the header/footer is changeable as usual.

Comment: Thanks! Werner. But doesn't work well if I add `\AtEndDocument{Some text}`, and in my document I have something as that.

Comment: My document is a two sided article with `\cleardoublepage`.

Comment: @osjerick: `\AtEndDocument` can be used multiple times - it doesn't get overwritten. With the additional information, please update your original question with a full, compilable, minimal example that shows your current setup.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Thanks. I've added your good suggestion.

Comment: @osjerick: I've updated my answer by means of using the [`pageslts` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/pageslts). It provides the label `VeryLastPage` that should take care of your current concerns.